# change mouse trail script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found this cool Codepen Mouse Trail script. How can I change it that it only works inside a div, and that it uses an image (of a cursor) instead the css-code (like it is 1996)? Tnx!

https://codepen.io/tomhodgins/pen/bgRVKL

```js
var coord = new Array(50)
function update(e){
  var x = e.clientX || e.touches[0].clientX
  var y = e.clientY || e.touches[0].clientY
  coord.push([x,y])
  coord.shift()
  EQCSS.apply()
}
document.addEventListener('mousemove',update)
document.addEventListener('touchmove',update)
```

```css
@element '[data-dot]' {
  $root, $this {
    cursor: none;
  }
  $this {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    position: fixed;
    left: eval("coord[50-(getAttribute('data-dot')*5)][0]")px;
    top: eval("coord[50-(getAttribute('data-dot')*5)][1]")px;
    opacity: calc(eval("10 - getAttribute('data-dot')") / 10);
  }
}
```

```html
<aside data-cursor>
  <div data-dot=10></div>
  <div data-dot=9></div>
  <div data-dot=8></div>
  <div data-dot=7></div>
  <div data-dot=6></div>
  <div data-dot=5></div>
  <div data-dot=4></div>
  <div data-dot=3></div>
  <div data-dot=2></div>
  <div data-dot=1></div>
</aside>
```

Comment: No offence, but cursors like that are _really_ obnoxious. That's probably the reason I haven't seen anything like that since 1996.

Comment: `document.document.getElementById("test").addEventListener('mousemove',update)
document.document.getElementById("test").addEventListener('touchmove',update)` Why would someone do this tho?

Comment: Thanks! I know it is annoying a mouse trail, it is for a site which is show all kinds of arty experiments. So in this case, this is what I'm looking for ;-)